# GraphQL and MongoDB `$geoNear` aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose, graphql

I am trying to retrieve some objects from my MongoDB database whose location is near a given set of coordinates and then order them nearest to farthest, which works. The issue is i also want to display the distance for each object e.g '1.3m away'.

I was previously using `$near` which worked perfectly but switched to use `$geoNear` because it is able to return the distance from the given coordinates by adding an extra field to the json returned for each object, e.g. a new `distance` field along with the existing fields.

`$geoNear` is described in the docs as an `aggregation` but not sure what difference that makes. I have got `$geoNear` working exactly how I had `$near` so retrieving the correct objects in the correct order but cannot retrieve that new `distance` field.

How do I ask GraphQL to return a field that only exists via the mongoDB query/aggregation?

Here is my resolver for this query:

```
  findNearestShops: async ({ coordinates }) => Shop.aggregate([
    {
      $geoNear: {
        near: { type: 'Point', coordinates },
        distanceField: 'distance',
        minDistance: 0,
        maxDistance: 8046.72,
        spherical: true
      }
    }
  ]),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the new `distance` field to my GraphQL schema for the object type I was searching for and adding it as a returned field for the GraphQL query on the front end seemed to do the trick.